# Misleading error "Unable to download" when there was no space

Tags: maven, archiva

I recently setup maven mirror proxy Archiva on my local machine. When users in my organization started to use it, all of sudden one person started to get `Unable to download artifact ...` .

Then we switched to original repo mirror. Turns out that this time we were getting `No disk space to 
write`.

I was wondering if anyone else has faced this issue ? Found any configuration setting to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

As a consumer of Archiva the message is correct: it didn't get the artifact. So you should analyze the problem: is it actually trying to reach Archiva? If so, go through the logs of Archiva and try to find the problem. In general it is not wise to send such detailed message (out of diskspace) back to the consumer, there's nothing he/she can do about it.

Comment: There is something he can do. He can make some space if he gets "no space left on device". Dont you think it's useful?

Comment: There's always a discussion how much info should be sent back to the user. For instance a failed login. If the system says that the user does exist, but doesn't have that password, that would be very, very useful info for a hacker. In this case: give the problem back to the maintainer of your Archiva-instance. He should be able to reproduce your issue and fix this. There's really no need for you as a user to know the cause, as long as it can be fixed.